# Title of product requirement are not visible

Tags: jira, confluence

I'm newest in Jira and want add some product requirements. When I add it, it shows in folder "Product requirements" but there's no title of this requirements. Can somebody tell me what's wrong ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJrqz.png)

Comment: you seem to use Content By Label macro that lists pages by label (+ other filter parameters), could you please give more information on the error? Did you put the label to PR page that is specified in the macro?

Comment: @AndriiMaliuta thanks, it was just a Jira error due to some technical works.